# Pentaho Spoon chrashes when rightclicking in the Explorer

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Every time I right-click in the Explorer on the left side (e.g. on Database Connections in the View-tab), Spoon crashes and I have to terminate it via task manager. The right click works on any other part of Spoon, except in the Explorer.

I tried uninstalling and installing JAVA again (32 and 64 bit) but it's still not working.

Does anybody have an idea? It's pretty annoying since I'm dealing with this for weeks now...

Comment: what are your PDI and java versions? I've seen it in the past and the solution was simply upgrade to Java 8.

Comment: I am running Java 8. PDI is running on version 7.

Comment: Try adding up more ram!

Comment: @realspirituals I am running 8Gb in my machine. You think that is not sufficient to run this tool?

Comment: How much is allocated to Pentaho? https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0H0/070/020/010